# how to create a plugin with class?

Tags: jquery

The following code will create a plugin with methods

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

And we can use like this:

```
$( "div" ).greenify({
    color: "orange"
});
```

But I want to know something like this

```
<div class="pluginclass"></div>
```

And then this should be as per plugin that is just using class in markup but not like `$('div').pluginclass();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of creating a function which needs to be called by the user, you just want to run a function on all divs matching your CSS class? This would be no different to writing any normal jQuery script:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var settings = { color: "white", backgroundColor: "green" };
    $(".pluginclass").each(function() {
        // Do work
    };
    // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
    $(".pluginclass").css({
        color: settings.color,
        backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
    });

}( jQuery ));
```

As soon as you include the above on the page, all `.pluginclass` divs will have their background set to green and their colour set to white.